# Does new Firebase Auth for polymer have changing password process included?

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, firebase-polymer, polymerfire

I can't find any sign of methods for reseting password or sending password reset email in the new [firebase-auth](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/master/firebase-auth.html) for Polymer 1.0 and above. Where can I find it if it exists? I would need it to be able to complete the sign in / up procedure.

I can see the old version for Polymer 0.5 and older that has the methods but the [documentation](https://github.com/Polymer/firebase-element/blob/master/firebase-login.html) says it's for Polymer 0.5 and older.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've linked to a file. The code in that file seems quite well documented. I'm not really sure what your question is beyond that.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for your comment, I must be missing then as I cannot find any method for resetting password or sending related emails in the new firebase-auth document (my first link). Do you mean the second document? Isn't that for Polymer older than 0.5 as it says in the link? Sorry if I seem quite confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just use all the standard firebase [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) methods directly on a firebase-auth's user property. ie something like:

```
<firebase-auth user="{{user}}"></firebase-auth>
<script>
  this.$.user.updatePassword(newPassword);
</script>
```

& of course following the requirements for this function specified in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#updatePassword

Answer (score 0):

Currently as (11/13/2016) polymfire is missing **sendPasswordResetEmail**. So you can't have a reset password email sent by the system. I have put in a pull request to fix this at: https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/pull/148.

You can create your own process with the above answer.

Comment: Thanks but if you see Frank's comment above , he seems to think it's all there. I haven't got a chance to get back to this yet but hopefully all works when I do get a chance. Cheers~